# Blueimp / Jquery-File-Upload - Thumbnails not working with large images

Tags: resize, size, blueimp

I'm having an issue using the UploadHandler.php. It does not resize images larger than 1.1M.
No errors are coming up. Everything else is working fine.

Server memory_limit = 120M

Post Max Size = 40M

Upload Max Filesize = 40M

Tried 'convert_params' => '-limit memory 120MiB -limit map 120MiB',

Thanks

Comment: In my case more than 10 MB sized image  (large image) getting error for generating preview. And as followed failed not upload. Any thoughts ?